# Updating Value in a table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to achieve this ..

```
update Table_A c 
set c.Column1 = 
(select d.column1 - b.column2
from Table_B d, Table_A b
where b.primary_key = d.primary_key)
```

But for outer query there is no primary key clause i have added.. How do i achieve it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  How do you know which row from the query that joins B and D to use for a particular row in C.  In other words, what column(s) in C would you join to either B or D?

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you want to do.

Also your aliases are confusing. If there is a Table_a and a Table_b don't name Table_a b.

```
update table_a a1
   set a1.column1 = (select b.column1 - a2.column2
                       from table_b b,
                            table_a a2   
                      where b.primary_key = a2.primary_key)
```

Comment: update table_a a1
   set a1.column1 = (select b.column1 - a2.column2
                       from table_b b,
                            table_a a2   
                      where b.primary_key = a2.primary_key 
        and  a1.key = a2.key)              
        
Thanks for your help.. I understood the problem

Comment: Won't this do? update table_a a1
   set a1.column1 = (select b.column1 - a1.column2
                       from table_b b
                      where b.primary_key = a1.primary_key)

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear, but I wonder if you meant to do a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) like this:

```
update Table_A a 
set a.Column1 = 
(select b.column1 - a.column2
from Table_B b
where b.primary_key = a.primary_key)
```

Note that the alias "a" in the subquery refers to the row that is being updated in the main query.